# getting partial result from hql when selecting normal columns + entities

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hql

I am running a query to get data from the following entity.

Product.java

```
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="product_id")
    private Long productId;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "product")
    private ProductDescription description;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "product")
    private ProductPrice price;

    @Column(name="is_master")
    private String isMaster;

    @Column(name="free_shipping")
    private String freeShipping;
}
```

On running the following query, I'm getting the correct result

```
String sql = "SELECT p.description, p.price "
            + "FROM " + Product.class.getName() + " p "
            + "WHERE p.productId = :productId";
```

However, if I run the following query then description and price return as null.

```
String sql = "SELECT p.description, p.price, p.isMaster, p.freeShipping "
            + "FROM " + Product.class.getName() + " p "
            + "WHERE p.productId = :productId";
```

There is no error in the logs, isMaster and freeShipping values are returned but description and price are coming as null.

Comment: its probably just a typo but you have description field mapped as product

Comment: No, that's for the Product reference, i.e. private Product product; , declared in ProductDescription class.

Comment: Can you also show the code where you are collecting the result i.e. how you are executing the code and collecting the result.